# How can I change the value of my int variable?

Tags: java, int

In my game I'm trying to increase the value of wood when I gather wood, but I can't figure out how. Here's my code:

```
package Main;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("In order to build your house, you need 25 wood"); //I haven't added building the house yet
        System.out.println("To gather wood type 'gather wood'. (no caps)"); 

        while (true) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random Random = new Random();   

        String getWood = "gather wood";

        int randomNumber = Random.nextInt(11);

        int wood = 0;   

        String s = scan.nextLine();

        if (s.contains( getWood )) {
            System.out.println("You have gathered " + randomNumber + " wood!");
        } else {
        }

        }
    }

}
```

When I type "gather wood" I want it to add an amount to the int variable "wood", preferably the same random number in "System.out.println("You have gathered " + randomNumber + " wood!");"

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks! :D

Comment: `wood += randomNumber;` ?

Comment: You are constantly creating a new variable called wood and setting it to zero. Put the variable above the while loop. Then in the loop at the place where wood initialization is now put: `wood += randomNumber;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to declare the variable wood outside of the while loop, otherwise it will always be reset to zero.
Then you can add the random number like this:

```
wood += randomNumber;
```

That is the short form for:

```
wood = wood + randomNumber;
```

Comment: It works! Thanks sooooo much! I feel like iv'e tried everything, and now i feel really dumb haha!

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
        System.out.println("In order to build your house, you need 25 wood"); //I haven't added building the house yet
        System.out.println("To gather wood type 'gather wood'. (no caps)"); 
        int wood = 0; 

        while (true) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random Random = new Random();   

        String getWood = "gather wood";

        int randomNumber = Random.nextInt(11);



        String s = scan.nextLine();

        if (s.contains( getWood )) {
            System.out.println("You have gathered " + randomNumber + " wood!");
            wood+=randomNumber ;
            System.out.println("You now have " + wood + " wood!");
        } else {
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement it would be:

```
if (s.contains( getWood )) {
            System.out.println("You have gathered " + randomNumber + " wood!");
            wood = wood + randomNumber;
        } else {
        }

        }
```

You may want to think about creating a class though and accessing the "wood" variable?

Answer (score 0):

Place `int wood = 0;` outside of your loop. You create a new variable with value 0 every loop.

You also need to place `wood += randomNumber;` inside the if statement. Otherwise the value of wood does not change.

Answer (score 0):

How to add one to a int variable

```
int something = 1;
something++;
```

The variable something will now be 2.

How to add an amount:

```
int something = 1;
something += 5;
```

The variable something will now be 6.

How to add more than 1 amount:

```
int something = 1;
something = something+1+1+1;
```

Now the variable something will be 4.

How to add an amount to a variable when creating variable:

```
int something = 1+3;
```

The variable something will now be 4.
I think thats what you mean when not comment what you did mean and i will try to help you!